# The semiring generated by $\mathbb{R}_+$ and the polynomials $x, y, x + y - 1, 1 - (x+y)$

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra

Let $S$ be the semiring in $\mathbb{R}[x,y]$ generated by the nonnegative real numbers $\mathbb{R}_+$ and the polynomials $x, y, x + y - 1, 1 - (x+y)$, i.e.
$$S = \left\{ \sum_{i,j,k,\ell \ge 0 } a_{i,j,k,\ell} x^{i} y^{j} (x + y - 1)^{k} (1 - (x+y))^{\ell}  : \,  a_{i,j,k,\ell} \ge 0 \,\, \forall i,j,k,\ell \,\right\}.$$
Let $\pi$ be the quotient map $\mathbb{R}[x,y] \twoheadrightarrow \mathbb{R}[x,y]/(x + y - 1)$.

Clearly $S \subseteq \pi^{-1}(\pi(S))$. Is the inclusion strict?

Comment: If you have 1-x-y in addition to x+y-1 then the restriction to nonnegative coefficients is inessential.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question can be reformulated as: *Does $\pi^{-1}(0)$ lie in $S$?* Indeed, if so, then for all $s\in S$, $t\in \mathbb R[x,y]$ with $\pi(s)=\pi(t)$ we have $t-s\in S$, so $t=s+(t-s)\in S$ as well.

And this seems to be true. Actually, every $t\in \pi^{-1}(0)$ is a linear combination of the polynomials $m_{ij}=x^iy^j(x+y-1)$; but both $m_{ij}$ and $-m_{ij}$ lie in $S$, thus $t\in S$ as well.